# When respawning as a Skulk, do I have to re-mutate?

Tags: natural-selection-2

I enjoy playing as a skulk, and towards the latter part of the game you can mutate with upgrades (extra armor, regeneration, extra energy, etc).

When I die and respawn, do I keep those upgrades, or must I mutate again each life?

Comment: Unless they changed it, you have to re-choose your mutations every time you spawn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get to re-evolve every life. This allows you to change the upgrades you have as the game progresses. For instance, celerity is better than adrenaline before you get leap, but with leap and wall jumping the extra leaps from adrenaline can be faster.